# React newbie. DOM doesnt update

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've received a react project where I need to make a complex state update my dom.

My component looks like this:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { iFGUSchema, iFGUSchemaQuestion } from './mockProgresson';
import { UTargetToggle } from './UTargetToggle';

interface USchemaTableProps {
    value : iFGUSchema;
  }

  export const CSchemaTable = (props: USchemaTableProps) => {
    const [workSchema, setWorkSchema] = useState(props.value);


    const checkClicked = (target : iFGUSchemaQuestion, value : number) => {

        loop1:
        for(var i=0; i< workSchema.headlines.length; i++){
            for(var o = 0; o < workSchema.headlines[i].questions.length; o++){
                if(workSchema.headlines[i].questions[o].ID == target.ID){
                    workSchema.headlines[i].questions[o].answer= value;
                    break loop1;
                }
            }
        }

        setWorkSchema(workSchema);

    }

    return (
    <div >
         <table>
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    workSchema.headlines && workSchema.headlines.map((headline) => {
                        return (
                            <Fragment>
                            <tr><td colSpan={5}><Typography>{headline.text}&hellip;</Typography></td></tr>
                                <Fragment>
                                {
                                    headline.questions && headline.questions.map((question) => {
                                        return (
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><Typography>&hellip;{question.text}</Typography></td>
                                                <td><UTargetToggle onClick={() => {checkClicked(question, 1)}} value={question.answer} targetValue={1} trueSlot={<div>aa</div>} falseSlot={<div>false</div>} /></td>
                                                <td><UTargetToggle onClick={() => {checkClicked(question, 2)}} value={question.answer} targetValue={2} trueSlot={<div>aa</div>} falseSlot={<div>false</div>} /></td>
                                                <td><UTargetToggle onClick={() => {checkClicked(question, 3)}} value={question.answer} targetValue={3} trueSlot={<div>aa</div>} falseSlot={<div>false</div>} /></td>
                                                <td><UTargetToggle onClick={() => {checkClicked(question, 4)}} value={question.answer} targetValue={4} trueSlot={<div>aa</div>} falseSlot={<div>false</div>} /></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                                </Fragment>
                            </Fragment>
                        );

                    })
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    )
  }
```

and the workSchema state contains a mock object looking like this:

```
{
    ID : 1,
    name  : 'Næse og navle-pilleri',
    type : 'theme',
    headlines : [
        { 
            ID : 11,
            text : 'How well do you ',
            questions : [
                {ID : 21, text : 'smell the fart', answer : 2},
                {ID : 22, text : 'like the smell', answer : 1},
            ]
        },
        { 
            ID : 12,
            text : 'How much do you',
            questions : [
                {ID : 23, text : 'want to leave the room', answer : 0},
                {ID : 24, text : 'want to join in', answer : 4},
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Now. I can see that the workSchema state is updated but the dom isn't updated.
I suspect I've misunderstood something in the way I use react but what?

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah..  GOT IT..
I cannot do this: edit a state directly and thereafter set it

```
state = workSchama.
workSchema.a = 'foo';
setWorkSchema(workSchama);
```

I must make a duplicate :

```
var dummyschema = {...workSchema}
dummyschema.a = 'foo';
setWorkSchema(dummyschema);
```

..and then it works

Comment: yep and `setWorkSchema({...workSchema,a:'foo'})` is even shorter